# prevent overlap of inputted text on a nested button inside EditText

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a nested button inside an EditText. I'm using a RelativeLayout to do that. The problem is that the text input is overlapping the button. How can I prevent this from happening? Perhaps a way to limit the characters per line. I have tried setting android:maxLength but it is applied to the whole EditText not per line.

[image]

```
   <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
           android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
           >
           <EditText
               android:id="@+id/item"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:background="@drawable/rounded_edit"
               android:ems="10"
               android:hint="samplehint"
               android:lines="5"
               android:maxLines="5"
               android:minLines="1"
               android:padding="10dp"
               android:paddingRight="50dp"
               android:inputType="textMultiLine"
               android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
               android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
           <Button
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="Done"
               android:layout_centerVertical="true"
               android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
               android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

           </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout`. Something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:gravity="center|start"
        android:text="Samplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesample"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding `android:drawablePadding="35dip"` to the EditText. But since it doesn't work without a drawable I added an empty drawable to direction of the button.

```
android:drawablePadding="35dip
android:drawableRight="@android:color/transparent"
```